# Associating user selection of a language for an application with the corresponding translation in an OLAP database

Tags: sharepoint, translation, multilingual, olap, performancepoint

Here is my problem: I have a multilingual SharePoint application and I have PerformancePoint reports in that application. In my OLAP database I have set up 3 translations for the dimension's and cube members for the corresponding languages that the application uses. 
My question is - how do I retrieve (select) the content from the OLAP cube for the selected language in the application. I don't know how to associate  the selected language in the application with the available translations in my OLAP database.
Your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on my own question so I'll share it for others that need it - the connection between the language selection of the user and the corresponding translation in the OLAP database is done with the connection string of the PPS data source. The connection string should look something like this:

"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW;Locale Identifier=LCID;"
where LCID is the Locale ID. List of LCIDs for all the languages you can find here: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;221435

So for example if the user has selected Macedonian language in the application, the connection string of the PPS data source should be:

"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW;Locale Identifier=1071;"